# How to scroll layout with adjustPan

Tags: android

I have a `nestedscrollview` in my `fragment` which is having button below of `nestedscrollview`, when keyboard arrives button moves above of the keyboard and the entire layout handle its scrolling properly but the issue is with the background image which get shrink.

I've used `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize"` in my Manifest file and if i use `adjustPan` then view does not scroll entire layout shift up.

I know this question is asked so many times but I didn't found proper answer.
Please Help.

Comment: hey,
Have you tried this one :
 getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.your_image_resource);


remove background image from XML file.

Comment: yes I've tried this too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow steps like below :
After that you are able to achieve what you want:(Below code is MainActivity.xml code)In this code Image View is your background image.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@color/colorAppBack"
  tools:context=".activities.LoginActivity">

   <ScrollView
      android:id="@+id/scrollView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:scrollbars="none">

      <ImageView
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:adjustViewBounds="true"
          android:src="@drawable/login_image_min_2" />
   </ScrollView>

// Your container layout which contains fragments like framelayout or what ever you are using
</RelativeLayout>
```

In manifest:

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your image is shrinking because you have added image inside scroll view too.
Try to add image out side the scroll view as image is background image.
This way Image wont scroll.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have image view in my activity xml and fragments are attached with that activity. Fragments are having transparent background to highlight that image. So what should i do in this case.